# Solucionar OutOfMemoryError al Descargar Archivos Grandes Desde Azure Blob Storage

Tags: java, spring-boot, azure, azure-storage

Cuando intento descargar archivos de más de 200MB de peso desde Azure Blob Storage se me presenta la excepción: `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError`

El flujo que utiliza mi aplicación es el siguiente:

1.- Método Principal:

```
public byte[] getFileBytes(@RequestBody ZeusRequestVO<String> request) {
return documentService.downloadFileByChunks(request).toByteArray();
}
```

2.- Lógica para la Descarga:

```
public ByteArrayOutputStream downloadFileByChunks(String blobName) {
long file_size = 0;
long chunkSize = 10 * 1024 * 1024;
CloudBlockBlob blob = connectAndgetCloudBlockBlob(blobName);
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
try {
    if (blob.exists()) {
        blob.downloadAttributes();
        file_size = blob.getProperties().getLength();
        for (long i = 0; i < file_size; i += chunkSize) {
            blob.downloadRange(i, file_size, baos);
        }
    }
} catch (StorageException e) {
    throw new GenericException(e, BussinesErrorEnum.AZURE_BLOB_STORAGE_EXCEPTION);
}
return baos;
}
```

Cabe resaltar que ya he configurado las propiedades `-Xms` y `-Xmx` mismas que solucionaron el problema en un inicio cuando la aplicación no era capaz de descargar archivos de más de 30MB. Los valores actuales son `-Xms1024m` y `-Xmx6144m`.

Encontré una posible solución [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65403169) pero al ser una aplicación de la empresa donde trabajo, no puedo actualizar las dependencias.

¿Algún consejo?

Comment: Te diré lo mismo que a otros, en el momento que llamas a `toByteArray()` estas cargando todo le archivo en la memoria, simplemente no lo llames y busca una alternativa

Comment: Soy consciente de las implicaciones en memoria de utilizar `ByteArrayOutputStream` y existen soluciones para reemplazarlo, solo que no he encontrado una compatible con la situación que mencioné arriba.